# Project disconnected vertex with Gremlin/Tinkerpop

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I am looking at a kryo file with the following vertices

```
# Tree Vertices
V(label=tree, properties={treeId:1, treeName:treeA})
V(label=tree, properties={treeId:2, treeName:treeB})

# Root Node Vertices
V(label=node, properties={treeId:1, nodeId:111, nodeType:root})
V(label=node, properties={treeId:2, nodeId:222, nodeType:root})
```

**There are no edges between the vertices labeled as tree and the vertices labeled as node.** There are further edges nodes connected to the root nodes but they are irrelevant to this question. I do not want to add any edges as this graph file gets vended to me and I am treating it as read-only.

Now I want to join/project the treeNames into a traversal over the root nodes.

```
g.V()
  .hasLabel('node').has('nodeType', 'root')
  .project('nodeId', 'treeId', 'treeName')  # return nodeId, treeId, treeName for each root node
  .by(values('nodeId'))
  .by(values('treeId'))
  .by("""  # pseudo-sqlish gremlin to clarify my intent
     select treeName 
     from V().hasLabel('tree')
       .where(values('treeid'), eq($thisNode.values('treeId'))
     """
   )
```

In SQL terms I'd say: I want to run a subquery (fully independent sub traversal starting from scratch) and then join it with my outer traversal on a given property. And again: No edge between trees and roots.

```sql
WITH
   trees as (SELECT treeId, treeName FROM vertices v WHERE v.label = 'tree'),
   roots as (SELECT nodeId, treeId FROM vertices v where v.label = 'node')

SELECT roots.nodeId, roots.treeId, trees.treeName
FROM roots
  JOIN trees ON (roots.treeId, trees.treeId)
```

So I am looking for a way to perform a projection based on another traversal + one of the returned vertex properties

- How abusive is this?
- How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by starting a new traversal inside the `project` like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('node').
  has('nodeType', 'root').as('root').
  project('nodeId', 'treeId', 'treeName').
    by(values('nodeId')).
    by(values('treeId')).
    by(coalesce(
        V().hasLabel('tree').where(eq('root')).
          by('treeId').
        values('treeName'),
        constant('tree not exist')
      ))
```

see the example here: https://gremlify.com/bybp7s9mdia

How abusive is this: **Very**.

starting a sub-query for each node vertex can be very 'heavy' performance-wise.
and it's missing all of the advantages of graph DB if your graph schema doesn't fit your requirement

Comment: Fantastic, thank you (also for confirming the level of abusiveness ). I was trying this for hours yesterday. I think I had managed to get the inner traversal right, but failed to make the reference to the outer alias.

Comment: I have a case where edges are linked to in/out vertices plust a third vertices. The only way I can see to model this is an edge property that points to the 3rd vertex, unfortunately I can't fine an efficient query for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76527659