# Gremlin, linking an edge to a vertex via property

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

In a graph database, I have graphs like:

```
v1: Protein{prefName: 'QP1'} 
  -- r1: part_of{evidence: 'ns:testdb'} 
  --> v2: Protcmplx{prefName: 'P12 Complex'}
ev: EvidenceType{ iri = "ns:testdb", label = "Test Database" }
```

I'd like to write a Gremlin query to fetch instances of the `part_of` relationship and return v1 and v2's prefName, along with the evidence's label. So far I've tried this:

```
g.V().hasLabel( containing('Protein') ).as('p')
  .outE().hasLabel( 'is_part_of' ).as('pr')
  .inV().hasLabel( containing('Protcmplx') ).as('cpx')
.V().hasLabel( containing('EvidenceType') ).as('ev')
  .has( 'iri', eq( select('pr').by('evidence') ) )
.select( 'p', 'cpx', 'ev', 'pr' )
  .by('prefName')
  .by('prefName')
  .by('label')
  .by('evidence')
.limit(100)
```

But it takes a lot of time for a few thousand nodes+edeges, and eventually, it doesn't return anything. I'm sure the values are there and I think the problem is with `has( 'iri', ... )`, but I can't figure out how to match an edge property with another property in an unconnected vertex.

The graph is modelled this way, cause the LPG model doesn't allow for hyper-edges (linking >2 vertices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way using `where()` and `by()`, but it is quite slow (11secs to get 100 tuples from a few thousands nodes+edges):

```
g.V().hasLabel ( containing ( 'Protcmplx' ) ).as ( 'cpx' )
  .inE().hasLabel ( 'is_part_of' ).limit ( 10 ).as ( 'pr' )
  .outV ().hasLabel ( containing ( 'Protein' ) ).as ( 'p' )  
.V().hasLabel ( containing ( 'EvidenceType' ) ).as ( 'ev' )
    .where ( 'ev', eq ( 'pr' ) ).by ( 'iri' ).by ( 'evidence' ) 
.select ( 'p', 'cpx', 'ev' )
.by ( 'prefName' )
.by ( 'prefName' )
.by ( 'label' )
```

Any help with optimisation would be welcome!

**EDIT**: following a suggestion from the comments (thanks!), I've rewritten the solution a bit (it's still slow) and used `.profile()` at the end, obtaining this:

```
Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
GraphStep(vertex,[])                                              123591      123591         507.179     9.09
HasStep([~label.containing(Protcmplx)])@[cpx]                         10          10          34.313     0.61
VertexStep(IN,[is_part_of],edge)@[pr]                                 13          13           5.089     0.09
RangeGlobalStep(0,10)                                                 10          10           0.094     0.00
EdgeVertexStep(OUT)                                                   10          10           1.618     0.03
HasStep([~label.containing(Protein)])@[p]                             10          10           0.065     0.00
GraphStep(vertex,[])                                             1738360     1738360        4574.578    81.99
HasStep([~label.containing(EvidenceType)])@[ev]                      510         510         447.546     8.02
WherePredicateStep(ev,eq(pr),[value(iri), value...                    10          10           6.747     0.12
NoOpBarrierStep(2500)                                                 10          10           1.444     0.03
SelectStep(last,[p, cpx, ev],[value(prefName), ...                    10          10           0.154     0.00
NoOpBarrierStep(2500)                                                 10           8           0.785     0.01
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -        5579.617        -
```

So, the problem seems to be that the second V() picks up all the vertexes before the filters from the former traversal (on the where) can be applied. However, I can't find a way to avoid this. Does Gremlin have subqueries?

**EDIT/2**: inspired by the suggestion in the comments to use two separated queries (thanks!), I've tried this:

```
evLabels = [:]
g.V().hasLabel ( containing ( 'Protcmplx' ) ).as ( 'cpx' )
  // Trying to put the limit early-on
  .inE().hasLabel ( 'is_part_of' ).limit ( 100 ).as ( 'pr' )
  .outV ().hasLabel ( containing ( 'Protein' ) ).as ( 'p' )
.select ( 'p', 'cpx', 'pr' )
  .by ( 'prefName' )
  .by ( 'prefName' )
  .by ( map{
    pr = it.get()
    evIri = pr.values ( 'evidence' ).next ();
    lbl = evLabels [ evIri ];
    if ( lbl != null ) return lbl;
    lbl = g.V().hasLabel ( containing ( 'EvidenceType' ) )
             .has ( 'iri', evIri )
             .values ( 'label' ).next ();
    evLabels [ evIri ] = lbl == null ? "" : lbl;
    return lbl;
  })
```

Which avoids a full cartesian product join by accumulating sub-query results into a map. This is much faster than the original query (like <1s for 100 edges), but not very simple to read, I'm sure there is a better way to write the same.

Comment: If the initial `g.V()` returns more than one result, the second `V()` will be executed that many times and can impact performance. Regardless, profiling the query to see where the time is being spent may be helpful. Which graph database are you using?

Comment: Thanks, @KelvinLawrence. I'm using ArcadeDB. Please, see how I changed my answer, `profile()` gave me some insights, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: You could try putting a `limit(1)` before the second `V` to reduce the cartesian product a bit but it's still going to fan out. I'm not familiar with any optimizations that Arcade DB may have for such cases. It may be faster to run two queries and inject the results from the first into the second.

Comment: Thanks again, @KelvinLawrence, it would be great if you could at least outline the two queries solution in an answer. Personally, I'm too new to Gremlin and I can't figure it out.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence. I've added another edit to my answer, which kind of follows your suggestion. I'm sure it could be written better.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I've just realised I was given a comment by the author of 'Practical Gremlin', WOW! Thank you so much for this and for the book! I've discussed this case with Luca from AracadeDB too: https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb/discussions/1168

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with ArcadeDB query optimizer and the `contains` operator. If remove contains and just use the label names, it would use the index and should return in <10ms:

```
evLabels = [:]
g.V().hasLabel ( 'Concept:Protcmplx:Resource' ).as ( 'cpx' )
  // Trying to put the limit early-on
  .inE().hasLabel ( 'is_part_of' ).limit ( 100 ).as ( 'pr' )
  .outV ().hasLabel ( 'Concept:Protein:Resource' ).as ( 'p' )
.select ( 'p', 'cpx', 'pr' )
  .by ( 'prefName' )
  .by ( 'prefName' )
  .by ( map{
    pr = it.get()
    evIri = pr.values ( 'evidence' ).next ();
    lbl = evLabels [ evIri ];
    if ( lbl != null ) return lbl;
    lbl = g.V().hasLabel ( 'EvidenceType:Resource' )
             .has ( 'iri', evIri )
             .values ( 'label' ).next ();
    evLabels [ evIri ] = lbl == null ? "" : lbl;
    return lbl;
  })
```

Comment: exact matching speeds it up a bit, but it doesn't make much difference, the original query using where() still takes about 2s for 10 results and .profile() still shows it does a full scan on EvidenceType, for the bottleneck is the join on pr.evidence  = EvidenceType.iri.

Your query here is the one using the collecting map approach, matching labels exactly helps, but just slightly.